# What about race condition in multithreaded reading?

Tags: multithreading, race-condition

According to [an article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-threads1.html) on IBM.com, "a race condition is a situation in which two or more threads or processes are reading or writing some shared data, and the final result depends on the timing of how the threads are scheduled. Race conditions can lead to unpredictable results and subtle program bugs." . Although the article concerns Java, I have in general been taught the same definition.

As far as I know, simple operation of reading from RAM is composed of setting the states of specific input lines (address, read etc.) and reading the states of output lines. This is an operation that obviously cannot be executed simultaneously by two devices and has to be serialized.

Now let's suppose we have a situation when a couple of threads access an object in memory. In theory, this access should be serialized in order to prevent race conditions. But e.g. the readers/writers algorithm assumes that an arbitrary number of readers can use the shared memory at the same time.

So, the question is: does one have to implement an exclusive lock for read when using multithreading (in WinAPI e.g.)? If not, why? Where is this control implemented - OS, hardware?

Best regards,
Kuba

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Reading memory at hardware level is done sequentially - you don't need to worry about concurrency at this level. Two threads issue read instructions and all the necessary stuff - setting addresses on the address bus and actual reads are implemented by the memory access hardware in such way that reads will always work right.

In fact the same is true for read/write scenarios except that when read and write requests are interleaved you will get different results depending on timing and this is why you need synchronization.

Answer (score 5):

As long as there's nothing changing the data, it's perfectly safe to be reading it from several threads. Even if two CPUs (or cores) race to access the memory for reading at the exact same clock cycle, their accesses will be serialized by the memory controller and they won't interfere with each other. This feature is essential for HW working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple answer to this question. Different API's (and different environments) will have different levels of multhreaded-awareness and multithreaded safety.